# Hive deduplication query

Tags: sql, hive, duplicates, hiveql, greatest-n-per-group

Working on a use case for deduplication and need some guidance -
A single table has customer records and their status -

[image]

The use case -

1. If for a customer multiple active and inactive records exist , we have to pull only one active record
2. If for a customer multiple active records exist , we have to pull only one active record
3. If for a customer multiple inactive records exist , we have to pull only one inactive record

I am trying with analytics function but no luck so far .
Any suggestions please.

Answer (score 2):

Use row_number() analytic function:

```
select customer, status
from
(
select c.*, row_number() over(partition by customer order by status)  rn
  from customer_table c
)s
where rn=1;
```

Comment: Thanks , it's working . Just one observation . shouldnt the order will be in asc mode ? like over(partition by customer order by status  asc )  because otherwise for an id where both "inactive" and "active" is there inactive will come as rn=1 and will be chosen but we want in such cases to select "active"

Comment: @PratikRudra It is ASC by default.Active will be assigned 1, Inactive 2